# Exporting a Sketch Prototype

Tags: prototype

**Is it possible to export a Sketch prototype as a working file?**

I have made a prototype and tested it but now I need to export it to show a stakeholder and give to my boss so he can use it in a meeting.

Im running Sketch 50.2, which is the latest version right now.

Are there any ways in Sketch, Plugins etc that I'm not aware of, or any recommendations on how to solve this?

Comment: We use invision to do all our prototyping with sketch. I think how quite a lot of UXers are using it now (in fact I didn't even know you could use sketch to build prototypes). Invision has a plugin called Craft which allows sketch and invision to talk to each other. If you haven't tried I recommend a trial - it works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a sketch user but a quick google search got me this:

> Once you’ve created a prototype you can preview it directly in Sketch, test it on iOS Sketch Mirror, and share it with clients or colleagues by uploading to **Sketch Cloud**.

https://sketchapp.com/docs/prototyping/

Comment: I did take a look at that and couldnt find any information however, digging deeper into some of the support info via your link I've come across a solution. Thank you for helping me get there!

Comment: https://sketchapp.com/docs/prototyping/previewing is where I found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your boss what he is going to present, Weather he wanted present the flow of the application, or explain the features of the APP etc.

If he wanted to present the flow and get the client input, upload the prototype in InVision and share him a link. Make sure he creates a account so that he can access the interaction.

If he wanted to display certain features, than better create the interaction as a small video using principle. You can present the steps and explain how it could benefits them.

Bottom line design files are different from the presentation file. Work closely with the boss to make the discussion successful.